# How to compare specific positions of two files that don't have delimiters

Tags: text-processing

I need to compare two files line-by-line. I want to output only those lines that are different, but when determining the difference, characters 4-6 and 10-12 should be ignored. There is no specific field delimiter or the like.

Example:

- file 1

  ```
  abc123def999
  ghi456klm999
  nop789qrs999
  ```
- file 2

  ```
  abc000def000
  xxx000yyy000
  nop000qrs000
  ```

In that example, only the second line should be different.

I don't want a `read` loop to parse the files line by line, as the files have millions of records.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What would you want as output from this example?

Comment: "I don't want a read loop to parse the files line by line..." -- Using a loop to read the file(s) line by line is what any program processing text ends up doing, so either this rules out every solution, is meaningless, or creates such an unspecified constraint that it's hard to even try to solve the problem here, since anything could be rejected based on that.

Comment: Length of lines are fixed and positions to ignore could be anything.

Comment: @André OK, [already posted my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669507/72456); **[edit]** your question and details into your question .

Comment: Output could be the same as a simple diff

Comment: Andrë it could be, yes, but if you don't tell us how can we know?

Comment: This is a very poorly specified question. Are the 2 files always the same number of lines as each other? Should the comparison be only on the same line number between the 2 files or for the strings occurring anywhere in the files? Can the same key substrings for comparison appear on multiple lines in a file and, if so, do the same numbers of those keys need to appear in each file or can 1 match multiple? What **exactly** should the output be given your posted sample input? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and probably provide better sample input/output that covers them.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk for the FIELDWIDTHS parameter:

```
$ paste file[12] |
    awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3' '$1!=$6 || $3!=$8'
ghi456klm999    xxx000yyy000
```

Here we used the `paste` command to paste both files side by side; then assuming that the lines in both files are in fixed length as we used the awk's FIELDWIDTHS parameter to define the fields length and then we are comparing the related fields for the difference; comparison here is line by line.

Alternatively using any awk in any shell:

```
$ paste file[12] |
    awk 'function key(s){return substr(s,1,3) substr(s,7,3)} key($1) != key($2)'
ghi456klm999    xxx000yyy000
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the expected output or really tell us what your requirements are so here's one guess at what you might want, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = substr($0,1,3) substr($0,7,3) }
NR == FNR {
    a[key]
    next
}
!(key in a)
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
xxx000yyy000
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
ghi456klm999
```

Answer (score 0):

Both files have "millions of records"? Pick the shorter file, read each line, generate a regular expression beginning with "`^`" (beginning of line), ending with "`$`" (end of line), with the search string in between. Set positions you want to ignore to "`.`" (the regular expression "match any single character"). E.g. "`^abc...def...$`". Save this in a temporary file (`file1.tmp`) (millions?). When you've processed all the lines `grep -E -f file1.tmp file2` will search for the regexps in `file1.tmp` in `file2`.

Comment: That approach fails when the files contain any regexp metachars.

Answer (score 0):

Method-1) `perl`

The `unpack` function is the most appropriate fir this scenario to extract specific character ranges based on the format which is supplied on the perl environment tray. `(A3x3)2A*` => select three ASCII characters then skip three chsracters. Repeat this process once more and then grab whatever else remains.

```
fmt='(A3x3)2A*' \
perl -nse 'print if "@{[unpack($ENV{fmt})]}" ne
"@{[unpack($ENV{fmt},scalar(<STDIN>))]}";
' -- -\"= File1 < File2
ghi456klm999
```

---

Method-2) `paste+GNU sed`

paste places the corresponding lines from the two files side-by-side and tab separated. hence, we assume the files should not have  a tab in them. Then we replace 4-6, 10-12 characters for both files' data with the same character "." before comparing the lines. When Ines do not match, print the file1 line.

```
# helper vars aid in writing sed code
x3='...'
A3="($x3)"
A3x3=$A3$x3
srch="^$A3x3$A3x3"
repl="\\1$x3\\2$x3"

paste File1 File2 |
sed -En 'y/\t/\n/;h
  '"s/$srch/$repl/Mg"'
  /^(.*)\n\1$/d;g;P
' -
```

---

Method-3) `Python`

The builtin zip function looks at lines side by side for the two files.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
# skip chars: 4-6 10-12
AoT = [(0,3),(6,9),(12,None)] # array of tuples

fx = lambda t: \
  a[t[0]:t[1]] != b[t[0]:t[1]]

ifile1,ifile2 = sys.argv[1:]
with open(ifile1) as f1,\
     open(ifile2) as f2:
  for a,b in zip(f1,f2):
    if any(map(fx,AoT)):
      print(a,end="")
' File1 File2
```